# Expression not assignable (Calculator without using * or /)

Tags: c++

I have to create a calculator but without using `*` or `/` within the code.  I keep on getting an

> "Expression not assignable"

error while trying to loop using addition for conducting multiplication.  Any suggestions?

```
char op;
int lhs, rhs; // stands for left-hand and right hand side of user input expression
int i;
int lhsnew;
int lhs2;

cout << "Enter the expression to run the calculator simulator: " << endl;
cin >> lhs >> op >> rhs;
//left hand side(lhs) operator right hand side (rhs)

switch(op)
// Switch based on operator chosen by user
{
    case'+':
    {
        cout << "The result is " << lhs + rhs << endl;
        break;
    }
    case'-':
    {
        cout << "The result is " << lhs - rhs << endl;
        break;
    }
    case'*':
    {
    // Here I made the loop control variable same as the rhs number submitted by user
        while(i >= rhs)
        {
            lhsnew = 0;
            lhsnew + lhs = lhsnew;

            i++;
            // Should I use a different looping method?
        }
        cout << "The result is " << lhsnew;`enter code here`
        break;
    }

    // Haven't included case for division
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lhsnew + lhs = lhsnew;` You can't do that. Did you mean `lhsnew = lhs + lhsnew;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lhsnew + lhs = lhsnew;
```

should be

```
lhsnew = lhsnew + lhs;
```

You just got it backwards I guess. But then why did you write the correct

```
lhsnew = 0;
```

instead of the incorrect

```
0 = lhsnew;
```

in C++ what you are assigning goes on the right hand side, and what you are assigning to (usually a variable) goes on the left hand side.

Also note that your loop is very wrong, it should be

```
    lhsnew = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i < rhs)
    {
        lhsnew = lhsnew + lhs;
        i++;
    }
```

1) You only want to assign zero to `lhsnew` once, so it should go before the loop, not inside the loop.

2) You never gave `i` a value before you used it, it needs to start at zero

3) You want to carry on looping while `i < rhs`, not while `i >= rhs`. You got the logic negated some how

Comment: or `lhsnew += lhs;`

Comment: @Ayxan yes but one step at a time.

Comment: `But then why did you write the correct` - when they don't understand that there's a difference they won't differentiate. :-)

Comment: and a *init*; while(*cond*) { *body*; *inc*; } is conventionally expressed as for(*init*; *cond*; *inc*) { *body*; }